# После отправки формы получаю пустой модель

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form, razor, submit

вот мой Controller`

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddCategory(CategoryViewModel model)
    {
         .......

        return View(model);
    }
```

вот мой model

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int ID;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    public int ParentID;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public string CategoryName;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    [Display(Name = "Category URL")]
    public string CategoryURL;
}
```

вот мой View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCategory", "Category", new { area = "Administration" }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ID)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CategoryName, new { @class = "control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9" })
            <div class="input-icon">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CategoryName, new { @class = "form-control ", @placeholder = "Category Name", @required = "required" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.CategoryName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ParentID, new { @class = "control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9" })
            <div class="input-icon">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentID, listItems, "-- Select Parent Category --", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ParentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CategoryURL, new { @class = "control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9" })
            <div class="input-icon">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CategoryURL, new { @class = "form-control ", @placeholder = "Url Name", @required = "required" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CategoryURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос код класса модели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените поля класса модели на свойства.

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int ID  { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    [Display(Name = "Category URL")]
    public string CategoryURL { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь.это помогло мне